# Unable to launch appium server programmatically under sandbox with eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, appium, ubuntu-16.04, sandbox

[image]

We are trying to build Appium project under sandbox with eclipse editor but Unable to set APPIUM_PATH  and  NODE_PATH value from eclipse environment variable tab under Run configuration

After setting the environment variable for APPIUM_PATH and NODE_PATH Still we are getting below error

```
Caused by:

io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidNodeJSInstance: Node.js
is not installed!   at
io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findDefaultExecutable(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:197)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
    at
io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:71)
    at
tomtom.gta.test.common.WebDriverManager.<clinit>(WebDriverManager.java:23)
    ... 40 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to
find executable for: node   at
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:987)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.<init>(OsProcess.java:63)   at
org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:38)  at
io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findDefaultExecutable(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:193)*
```

Here I can see we are getting an exception for Node is either not installed or invalid but manually I can see node has been installed successfully and path or environment variable is also correct on eclipse

Comment: Are you able to run appium in terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be problem with node and appium installation. 
Please follow node installation: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#windows

Install appium via npm: npm install -g appium

You can also install appium doctor to check that everything is working fine in your system: npm install appium-doctor appium-doctor

Now launch the appium doctor and check everything. Also you need to setup proper path of node in eclipse.